# Adding result of two different queries in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble writing a query. I have been working with UNION on two queries and they work just fine. My problem comes when I try to add the result of two queries.

Here is something to explain myself.

```
//Query 1
select count(id) from table1   <-- This gives a result of 2 
//Query 2
select count(id) from table2   <-- This gives a result of 1


//What I want to do is to add the two queries (2 + 1 = 3):
(select count(id) from table1) + (select count(id) from table2) <-- Which gives a result of 3.
```

When I execute this query, this error appears:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+
```

I think I should not use the "+" sign. Is there any way to do this?
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have a SELECT around the whole query:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table1) + (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table2) AS count
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT (select count(id) from table1) + (select count(id) from table2) from dual;
```